# one recessed light not working?

Tags: recessed-lighting

one of my eight recessed lights (HALO H71CT) is not working. What are the chances that it is the thermocoupler? The light doesn't come on and go off it just doesn't come on....thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Often the tang is flattened to the point it no longer contacts bulb bottom contact. Make sure power is off and lift the tang up in the sockets bit. Also look closely to ensure it is not coated with paint overspray or other crud.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from a brief description. However, that model of light lists that it uses push-in wire connectors, and it's possible those aren't making a solid connection. If you have access to this light, test the voltage.